# MySQL Query for first Datetime Item of a Day

Tags: mysql

I've got a Database in MySQL with around 1,000,000 DateTime Entries (Format: 2022-01-31 19:45:39) and so on.

For each day I have 100 Entries. I need a query to get the first DateTime Entry of the day, for the last 30 Days, where Column Number = 1234.

In PostgreSQl I would use a Lateral Join, but how to deal with it in MySQL?

Schema:

```
id           int(11) auto_increment
datetime     datetime   
number       varchar(255)
```

Someone can give me a full working example? I can't get it working

Comment: What is your schema? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: id int(11) Auto-Inkrement 
datetime datetime 
number varchar(255)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: Not really, how would I group them? I mean I can get the last 30 Days like: 'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)' <= 'datetime' but then I have records of 30 days and still can't get the first of each day.

Comment: The common day groups them, doesn't it?

Comment: What I've tried was "group by datesub(curdate()) order by datetime limit 1" but thats not working at all.

Comment: `GROUP BY LEFT(datetime, 10)` to group by individual days.